# In pyspark, why does `limit` followed by `repartition` create exactly equal partition sizes?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

According to the [pyspark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition), `repartition` is supposed to use hash partitioning, which would give slightly unequal partition sizes. However, I have found that by preceding it with `limit`, it will produce *exactly* equal partition sizes. This can be shown by running the following in a pyspark shell:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([range(5)] * 100)

def count_part_size(part_iter):
    yield len(list(part_iter))

print(df.repartition(20).rdd.mapPartitions(count_part_size).collect())
# [4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5]

print(df.limit(100).repartition(20).rdd.mapPartitions(count_part_size).collect())
# [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

If `repartition` is using a hash partitioner, why would it produce exactly equal partition sizes in this case? And if it is not using a hash partitioner, what kind of partitioner is it using?

By the way, I am using python version 2.7.15 and spark version 2.0.2

Answer (score 4):

There are four factors here:

- If no partitioning expression is provided, `repartition` doesn't use `HashPartitioning`, or to be specific, it doesn't use it directly. Instead it uses `RoundRobinPartitioning`, [which](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1b575ef5d1b8e3e672b2fca5c354d6678bd78bd1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/exchange/ShuffleExchangeExec.scala#L259) (as you can probably guess)

  > Distributes elements evenly across output partitions, starting from a random partition.

  Internally, it generates a sequence of `scala.Int` on each partition, [starting from a random point](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1b575ef5d1b8e3e672b2fca5c354d6678bd78bd1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/exchange/ShuffleExchangeExec.scala#L260-L265). Only these values are passed through `HashPartitioner`.
- It works this way because `Int` `hashCode` is simply identity - in other words

  *∀x∈Int x = hashCode(x)*

  (that's BTW the same behavior as of CPython `hash` in the Scala `Int` range - -2147483648 to 2147483647. These hashes are simply not designed to be cryptographically secure) As a result applying `HashPartitioner` to a series of `Int` values results in actual Round Robin assignment.

  So in such case `HashPartitioner` works simply as a modulo operator.
- You apply `LIMIT` before repartition so all values are shuffled to a single node first. Therefore there is only one sequence of `Int` values used.
- Number of partitions is a divisor of the size of the dataset. Due to that data can be uniformly distributed among partitions.

Overall it is a combination of intended behavior (each partition should be uniformly distributed among output partitions), properties of pipeline (there is only one input partition) and the data (dataset can be uniformly distributed).

Comment: Nice concise explanation.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed answer. I have a follow up question for you: is there a way to make this partitioning deterministic, such that it will send the same rows to the same partitions regardless of where the spark application is being run?

Comment: No, First of all there is a non-configurable random initialization baked into process. Second of all it depends on the order of values, which is often non-deterministic by itself. If you want deterministic  partition membership you should provide deterministic partitioning expression.